# Get the child element of another child element directly using map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using [REST Countries API](https://restcountries.com/v2/all?fields=name,area) for a course exercise, for example all I need is the **common** of the **name** from the data, and later do **common** with filter() ,I write like this:

```
const name = countries.map((c) => c.name);
const commonName = name.map((n) => n.common);

filteredName = commonName.filter((n) => n.toLowerCase().includes(findCountry.toLowerCase()))
```

It works, but the variable name will not be used anymore, so maybe looks stupid?

If I write like this:

```
const name = countries.map((c) => c.name.map((n) => n.common);
```

or:

```
filteredName = name.common.filter((n) => n.toLowerCase().includes(findCountry.toLowerCase()))
```

totally not works.

I'm new to this and have read the MDN documentation on array and map(). Just like to know if there is an obvious way to extract the common from the data to make some functions.

THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: I think I was getting wrong, I don't need a specific **common** name, just want it to do filter() and get the data with right name. thank you for watching!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map all `name.common` from all data (api `/all`).

```js
const commonNames = fetch(`//restcountries.com/v3.1/all`)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => r.map(c => c.name.common))
  .then(names => console.log( `find Namibia: ${
      names.find(n => n === `Namibia`)}\n\nAll names:\n\n${
        names.join(`\n`)}`) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```